# Compare current date with date written from text file is less than one week

Tags: php, file, datetime, file-io

I am reading from a text file line by line, in each line is formated like

```
05/20/2014 10:18:28 am

m/d/y h:m:s
```

How can I compare this with current date and select dates that are not less than one week?
This is what I have done so far but I'm wondered if there is any other easier way:

```
$arr = explode(' ',trim($line));
$fword = explode("/", $fword);
$fword =  $arr[0];
list($m,$d,$y) = explode("/", $line);
mm= date('m');
dd = date('d');
```

By the way, I am writing to text file in this format:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about string manipulation and date functions, use DateTime class instead - it's designed for this kind of tasks.

```
//Current time
$now = new DateTimeImmutable();
//One week ago
$oneWeekAgo = $now->sub(new DateInterval('P1W'));

//Read whole file into array
$lines = file('test.txt', \FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | \FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines AS $line) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i:s a+', $line);
    //Here you can compare your dates like any other variables
    if ($date > $oneWeekAgo) {
        //Current date is less than 1 week "old"
    }
    if ($date < $oneWeekAgo) {
        //Current date is more than 1 week "old"
    }
}
```

For different date/time periods see http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php. For example, if you would like to do same thing for "1 day ago", it would be ->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')), "1 year into the future" would be ->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copy pasted but for this line===> 05/20/2014 10:18:28 am  ===>
Current date is more than 1 week old

Comment: @Bernard yes, there was a typo, it should be working now - see edited answer.

Comment: Still is not working. Even for today date it says more than 1 week old.

Comment: @Bernard well then it seems that there is something wrong with date formats that are coming from your file. I tested in my local machine and for 'm/d/Y h:i:s a' format it works perfectly. You can try to var_dump($line); and var_dump($date); inside foreach loop and see what is going on. If var_dump($date); is false, there is something wrong with date format - see [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for formatting.

Comment: @Bernard you can also use 'm/d/Y h:i:s a+' format (note extra + mark), I included it in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfect now. I actually change the writing format to 'm/d/Y h:i:s a' as well.

Comment: Can you just tell me how can I change it to one day ago? I guess it is in $now->sub(new DateInterval('P1W'));

Answer (score 1):

you can use `strtotime` for it.

```
$current_time = strtotime(date('d-M-Y g:i:s A'));

$one_week = 3600 * 24 * 7;

// your file code
$fword =  $arr[0]; // assuming that $fword has file date.

// $fword = str_replace("/", "-", $fword);
$file_time = strtotime($fword);

$diff = $current_time - $file_time;
if($diff>$one_week)
{
   echo " date : ".$fowrd." is older than one week <br/>";
}
else 
{
   echo " date : ".$fowrd." is not older than one week <br/>";  
}
```

Comment: I just checked with today date which is $fword = 05/20/2014  ==> but I got is older than one week

Comment: ok no problem remove line `$fword = str_replace("/", "-", $fword);` or try updated code.

Comment: @Bernard have you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use date and strtotime methods

```
$t = '05/02/2014 10:18:28 am';
$aWeekLater = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($t.' -1 week'));
$curDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ($curDate < $aWeekLater) {
    echo 'xxx';
} else {
    echo 'yyy';
}
```

Comment: This would be the correct way to do it if you need to consider time-of-day across DST changes.

Comment: I want to find $t is less than one week or not, but I always I get yyy? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $line = 04/20/2014 10:18:28 am  but I get yyy

Comment: if you get yyy, it means curDate is greater than $t - 1 week (obviously, May 20 is greater than April 25)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (60*60*24*7+time() < strtotime(trim($line))) {
    // greater than 1 week in future
} else {
    // within 1 week from now
}
```